# mklink access denied but explorer succeeds

Tags: windows, mklink

Trying to create link on file share using:
mklink /D "\fileshare\dest\folder_link" "\fileshare\dest\folder"
(under Admin)

But it gives access denied, tried to run fsutil, but no success :(

`fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1`

`C:\Windows\system32>fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation
Local to local symbolic links are enabled.
Local to remote symbolic links are enabled.
Remote to local symbolic links are enabled.
Remote to remote symbolic links are enabled.`

However when I try to create link via explorer ( right clicking, selecting Create shortcut )- it works.

Why command line doesn't not work, but explorer does ?
Is there an alternative way to create soft links via cmd?

Comment: (1) Explorer shortcuts are **not** symbolic links, so your ability to create shortcuts in Explorer does not imply anything about your ability to create symbolic links. (2) In addition to being logged in as an admin, you need to be running an elevated command prompt process to create symlinks. Command prompts do not launch elevated by default.

Comment: CMD is elevated as UAC is turned off.
Hm, explorer shortcut was looking exactly as link ( without extension .lnk )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appeared to be GPO policy for linking not set on the machine that was hosting the fileshare.

> secpol.msc, Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Create symbolic

Comment: This doesn't seem to completely solve the problem for me.  I cannot run fsutil behavior set symlinkevaluation /? unless im in a Console Run as Admin. I have Create symbolic Links setup correctly. There has to be another permissions somewhere. Anyone know?